# Upload JSON Request as a background task in Flutter

Tags: flutter, background-process, flutter-android

I have a requirement where I want to upload JSON request data(fetch from database tables) to server and get the response, based on response I have to update local database(**sqflite: ^1.2.1**).
I have multiple screens and I need to create different JSON request data on every screen based on user action. Currently for same scenario I am using Intent Service in my another native android application.
What is the based way to handle such type of scenario in flutter Android application. If I use channel and implement Intent Service then I can't access sqflite database in Android specific region. If internet is not available then I have to keep waiting for connectivity, when device get connectivity then I need to upload all the created events to server one by one.

Please someone advise me the based possible way to handle this specific scenario in **Flutter**.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Save your JSON requests locally first using sqflite or sharedPreferences for instance. Once they are synced to your served, remove them from sync queue

Comment: Thank You for your comment. I am already saving user action as an events in sqflite database and then fetching required data to create JSON request, but I have thousands of JSON requests, in that case I want background service type mechanism that should handle JSON request syncing internally without blocking the UI in Flutter.

Comment: I tried to implement background_fetch plugin but unfortunately I got some issues in implementation, so couldn't completed. I am looking for better solution.

Comment: i have a question is sharedpreference or sqflite run on background using flutter_background_services ? as like app is close or destroy then data is fetch from sqflite or sharedpref.is anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution: I am able to access SQFlite database in native through channel.

This is the path of the database created in flutter

```
   "/data/data/{package name}/app_flutter/{database file name}"
```

So we can access like in native using channel

```
  SQLiteDatabase mDatabase= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/{package name}/app_flutter/{database file name}", null, 0);

  Log.i("MainActivity", "mDatabase.isOpen():"+mDatabase.isOpen());//check DB is open or not
  String query = "SELECT * FROM {Table Name}";
  Cursor cursor=mDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do{
       String data= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex({Table Column Name}));
       Log.i("MainActivity", "Column Data Value:"+data);
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
  }
  cursor.close();
```

So I will implement Service in native to achieve this scenario.
Thank You